# Theme not applying correctly on DialogFragment with AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I can't seem to get themes to apply correctly on my DialogFragment/AlertDialog.

Here's the code:

```
protected static class TabRenameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{

    public static TabRenameDialogFragment newInstance(long tabId, CashierActivity ca) {

        // create new dialogfragment and initialize items
        TabRenameDialogFragment trdf = new TabRenameDialogFragment();

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putLong("TAB_ID", tabId);

        trdf.setArguments(b);

        return trdf;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final DialogFragment fm = this;

        // set data
        final long id = getArguments().getLong("TAB_ID");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Styled_Dialog)
                // .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle("Rename " + cTabName)
                .setView(view)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Set",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        }
                    }
                ).setNegativeButton("Cancel", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            // nothing!
                        }
                    })
                .create();
    }

}
```

I'm using the 2 argument constructor for AlertDialog.Builder() to set the theme; it sets the theme correctly, but an odd border appears around the dialogfragment itself. I figure this is because I theme the AlertDialog inside the DialogFragment, but I don't know how to get rid of the outside part. I've already tried setting the style on the DialogFragment to STYLE_NO_FRAME and the like.

[image: Dialog Bug]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here are the styles I'm applying:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled.Dialog" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.DropDownListStyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.DropDownListStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle.Styled</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/bg_color_main</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/bg_color_main_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitle.Styled" parent="@style/DialogWindowTitle.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Styled.DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Styled.DialogWindowTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Light.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/bg_color_main</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you update the question & attach the styles you've defined for the dialog?

Comment: Updated with theme, I'm using ActionBarSherlock, but the problem still exists even if I use Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog (or any Holo dialog theme)

Answer (score 0):

One option is the override the windowBackground style like so:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
```

With the color defined like so:

```
<color name="transparent_white">#00FFFFFF</color>
```

This still isn't ideal because the resulting window is still a bit narrower then if you went with the default style.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the Dialog obtained from the AlertDialog.builder, get the DIalog and remove the background:

```
Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(...);
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.requestWindowFeature(STYLE_NO_TITLE);
return dialog;
```

I have not tested, but it shoud work (tell me if not).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```